# Clear button Settings on a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am using a form and was wondering if anyone knows some JavaScript that can edit what fields the clear button actually clears?

i.e i only want a select number of fields to be cleared once the user hits the clear button on the form.

```
input id='FrmReset' type='reset' value='Clear' name='resetButton' onclick='formReset(document.getElementById("Form")); return false;'
```

I just have the following which clears everything

```
<input id='FrmReset' type='reset' value='Clear' name='resetButton' onclick='formReset(document.getElementById("Form")); return false;' />
```

Comment: Just implement a standard button and a JS function that clears only fields you need.

Comment: show what you tried. Add a fiddle

Comment: Thanks Yuriy, could you elaborate with a quick example?

Comment: Code goes in your question.

Comment: You'd simply set the value of each input to empty. Rather than doing it all in an onclick attribute, write a function and call it on click.

Comment: @user3207341 see a small example in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have 4 fields like this:

```
<input type="text" value="don't clear this" id="i1" />
<input type="text" value="don't clear this" id="i2" />
<br/>
<input type="text" value="clear this" id="i3" />
<input type="text" value="clear this" id="i4" />
```

And you need to clear only bottom 2. Add a normal button with onclick event:

```
<button onclick="clearNeeded()">Clear only bottom fields</button>

function clearNeeded() {
    document.getElementById('i3').value='';
    document.getElementById('i4').value='';
}
```

As you can see - the function selectively picks only specific fields and resets their values.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rdnT3/

Comment: Fantastic thank you for the really clear answer much appreciated!

Comment: instead of value can you use .placeholder to keep a hint text when button is clicked?