# How to have a "clear fields" link for certain inputs

Tags: html, css

I need to have a link that clears the inputs in a certain column. I've found a way to style a button to look like a link:

```
<input type="reset" value="clear fields" style=" background:transparent; border: none; color:blue; cursor:pointer">
```

My page is set up in three columns and I need that link to only clear the inputs in the first column (the column with the link). How would I do that?

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="cardNumber">CARD NUMBER</label><!--<a>clear fields</a>-->
     <button onclick="clearFields()" style=" background:transparent; border: none; color:blue; cursor:pointer">clear fields</button>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cardNumber" placeholder="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="expiration" style="display: inline-block; margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;">EXPIRATION</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="expiration" placeholder="MM/YYYY" style="display: inline-block; width: 100px; margin: 5px;">
     <label for="cvv" style="display: inline-block; margin: 5px;">CVV</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cvv" placeholder="" style="display: inline-block; width:60px; margin: 5px;">
</div>
```

**EDIT**

```
var clearFields = function() {
    document.getElementById('cardNumber').value = '';
    document.getElementById('expiration').value = '';
    document.getElementById('cvv').value = '';
};
```

Comment: Don't use `type="reset"` instead create a small JavaScript function that sets only fields you need to blank: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23548304/961695

Comment: It seems like that would work, but I get this error: Cannot set property 'value' of null. See my edit.

Comment: Seem to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/6Ph5s/ are u sure in your real app names match as well?

Comment: Huh, that's odd that it works fine in the fiddle but not my file. I'm not sure why that is, everything seems to be named the same.

Comment: okay i got it to work now. I'm using knockout in my project so i had to take care of an error from ko. Thanks for your help!

Comment: no problem :) glad it worked for u

Answer (score 0):

This fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JjGm3/ shows how to do this in JavaScript.

```
var clear = document.getElementById('clear-fields');

//add event listener
clear.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  //set input
  var input = document.getElementById('test1');
    //clear input
    input.value='';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it with a hyperlink (http://jsfiddle.net/7fARG/):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="test" id="test1" />
<a href="#" onclick="clearFields(); return false;">Clear Fields</a>
```

Javascript:

```
window.clearFields = function() {
    document.getElementById('test1').value = '';
};
```